# JQuery Validation Error inside of ASP.NET textboxes?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation, error-handling

So I'm trying to make, for example, the username error string to be applied to textbox.Text.

Here's what I have. I'm sure I'm probably close...

```
        $("#formLogin").validate({
        messages: {
            '<%=textUsername.ClientID%>': {
                required: "<br />-Required-",
                minlength: "<br />-Minimum 3-",
                maxlength: "<br />-Maximum 15-"
            },
            '<%=textPassword.ClientID%>': {
                required: "<br />-Required-",
                minlength: "<br />-Minumum 6-",
                maxlength: "<br />-Maximum 15-"
            }
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            error.appendTo($('#<%=textUsername.ClientID%>').val(),
               $('#<%=textPassword.ClientID%>').val());
        }
    });
```

Thanks.

EDIT: HTML

```
        <form runat="server" id="formLogin">
        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="checkboxRemember" />
        <div><span id="un">Username</span><div id="forgotUsername">?</div><br />
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="textUsername"
            Class="required" MinLength="3" MaxLength="15" /></div>
        <div><span id="pw">Password</span><div id="forgotPassword">?</div><br />
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="textPassword" TextMode="Password"
            Class="required" MinLength="3" MaxLength="15" /></div>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="buttonLogin" Text="L" />
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="buttonRegister" Text="R" />
    </form>
```

Comment: Are you using a plugin?, can you post a little bit of the html?

Comment: Yeah, using the validator plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll probably want to rewrite your errorPlacement function to something like this:

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    // element is the object on which the error occurred 'textUsername'
    // error is a jQuery object of your error message '<br />-Required-'
    element.val(element.val() + error.val());
}
```